# When the stop word removal process is executed in sklearn TfidfVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, stop-words, tfidfvectorizer

If I pass a list of custom stopwords to [`TfidfVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html), when will the stopwords be removed exactly? According to [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html):

> **stop_words** : `string` {‘english’}, `list`, or `None` (default)
>
> ...
>
> If a list, that list is assumed to contain stop words, all of which
>   will be removed from the resulting tokens. Only applies if `analyzer == 'word'`.

so it seems that the process happens *after* the tokenization, am I right? The doubt arises because if the tokenization also involves stemming, I think there is the risk to erroneously skip (not remove) a stopword because, after stemming, it is not recognized anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so it seems that the process happens after the tokenization, am I right?

You are right. The `stop_words` are applied once the tokens are already obtained and are turned into a sequence of n-grams, see [`feature_extraction/text.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L125). The tokenizer receives the text right after the pre-processing, no stop words are involved.

The default tokenizer doesn't transform the text, but if you supply your own tokenizer that performs stemming or something like that, you are expected to stem the stop words as well. Alternatively, you can do the filtering right inside the tokenizer function.

Comment: Thanks, so if I want to do the removal process before passing the corpus to sklearn, after having tokenized and stemmed the corpus, I guess I just need to do something ike tokens = [w for w in tokens if w not in stop_words]. You mentioned n-grams but I think the n-grams (if n > 1) are produced later: 1) tokenization 2) stopwords removal 3) n-grams, am I right? Finally, I still have the doubt I mentioned at the end of the question: I can't think about a concrete example but if a word is a stopword but after stemming is not, it won't be removed.

Comment: `tokens = [w for w in tokens if w not in stop_words]` is exactly what scikit-learn does, see GitHub link I provided. After which it deals with n-grams.

Comment: Thanks again, any clue about the problem I mentioned (stopwords not removed because, after stemming, they are not stopwords anymore)?